# Hibernate custom type access result set

Tags: java, hibernate

My class implements Hibernate custom user type. implements UserType, ParameterizedType.

```
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] params, Object owner) throws SQLException {
```

I need to access a status fields via resultset parameter. So I have two ways of access.

1. By giving the column number resultSet.getString(17);
2. specifing the column name. Hiberbate returns

   ```
   resultSet.getString("STATUS13_51_0_"); //STATUS13_51_0_
   ```

Hibernate generates the query with own alias and so I can access with alias not with the column name.

The problem: this class get called from different places I need to access each time the status column.

As the incoming query is different the receiving column number and generated field alias is different.

What is the approach, solution you can suggest me to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `resultSet.getString` method on appropriate element from `param` array. There is no need to use hardcoded aliases.
E.g.

```
resultSet.getString(params[0]);
```

Simple example with mapping:

**Mapping**

```
<property name="propertyName" type="yourUserType">
   <column name="columnName1" />
   <column name="columnName2" />
</property>
```

or

```
@Type(type="com.package.usertypes.YourUserType")
@Columns(columns = {
    @Column(name="columnName1"),
    @Column(name="columnName2")
})
private CustomClass propertyName;
```

**User type**

```
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, 
                          String[] params, 
                          Object owner) throws SQLException 
{
   resultSet.getString(params[0]); // value of 'columnName1' column
   resultSet.getString(params[1]); // value of 'columnName2' column
   //
}
```

Comment: I can access the params array for the annotated columns. If I want to access columns which are non annotated have to use resultset. I am capturing annotated field with params. I think resultSet parameter is intend to that purpose is not it ?

Comment: @user3558691 It's unexpected usage of user type. You should specify all used columns in `@Columns`. It is bad practice to access separate column

Comment: Then what is the real usage of having resultSet as a parameter ?

Comment: private String getStatusField(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException{
                                                                  int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();        
        for (int i = 1; i < columnCount; i++) {
            if(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i).startsWith("STATUS"))
                return resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i);
        }     
        
        return null;
    }

Comment: @user3558691 `ResultSet` is needed to get values for `params` columns

Comment: I need to know if I access non annotated fields is it a bad practice

Comment: Thanks. As in the 4th comment I posted.